# the bundle is invalid. an application targeting the iphone device family may not require a iphone os deployment target of 3.2

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm making an iphone only app, so far I have been able to share my app via ad-hoc distributions, and run it both in my simulator and my devices. But now that I'm finished, I can't upload my build to the store because of this error:

"The bundle is invalid. an application targeting the iphone device family may not require a iphone os deployment  target of 3.2, wich is an ipad-only os"

The only Base SDK that I have after upgrading to xcode 3.2.3 are iphone device 3.2 and iphone device 4.0.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application and/or target build settings, ensure the Base SDK is set to **iPhone Device 4.0**. For now, all apps are supposed to use this as the Base SDK.

Then, find the *iPhone OS Deployment Target* build setting. You want to set this to the lowest version of iOS that your application supports. If it supports 3.0, enter 3.0. If you are using functionality that was added in iOS 3.2, then you should just enter 4.0 since 3.2 does not run on the iPhone.